# Why doesn't this function return a pointer after the first call?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int* intptr ()
{
    int i;
    i=rand();
    printf("%d_____",i);
    return(&i);
}

int main()
{
    int* j,k,l;
    j=intptr();
    k=intptr();
    l=intptr();
    printf("%d/n",j);printf("%d/n",k);printf("%d/n",l);
}
```

Here the `intptr` function returns a pointer in the first call and after that all the subsequent calls return the int `2752220`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers address undefined behavior, which is the poor coding practice your code sample exhibits.  However, as shown [here](http://cpp.sh/76kjc), the real issue is that when you define

```
int* j,k,l;
```

only the first variable `j` is an int pointer.  The others are regular integers.  In order to make them all pointers, you have to define them like this:

```
int* j; 
int* k;
int* l;
```

By running the code by chance each pointer may point to the same *deleted value* from your function, but at least they'll be pointers and not integers.

Comment: completely ignored it in answer :(

Answer (score 6):

In your code, `int i;` is local to the `intptr ()` function. You cannot return the address of `i` and use that in the caller. it  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, the lifetime of `i` has ended when the `intptr ()` function has returned. The address you're returned (or tried to return) has become *invalid.* Using the return value is thus, UB.

---

After that, please note

1. `k` and `l` are of type `int`, and you're *trying* to store an `int *`. Wrong. The result is implementation-defined (refer §6.3.2.3, `C11`) and most likely that is not something you wanted in your code.
2. `j` being a pointer, the correct way to *print* the pointer address is to use

   ```
   printf("%p/n",(void *)j)
   ```

   using wrong type of argument (`%d` expects `int`, not `int *`) is again UB.

Comment: even so,the function must return the address of the memory location where i was stored during its execution.When its lifetime has ended the memory location may be overwritten but its address would still be the same

Comment: @NamanJain: No, you're invoking UB. Technically an optimizing compiler may detect (and modern compilers actually *will* detect) that you're returning the address of an object which lifetime already ended when the result of that return turns into an r-value. A compiler is in its full right to produce **anything** in that situation; it's in its full right to emit a program that equals to `rm -rf /` and does just that when executing.

Comment: Once the `inptr()` function ends, the `i` doesn't exist anymore.  The address pointing to it points to garbage.  We don't know what's at the memory location once `i` is destroyed at the end of the function.

Comment: @brandaemon, , I know the address will point at garbage, but we should still get an address right ? instead of an int* an int is getting returned

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to return something, which is local to the function `intptr()`, hence whatever output you are getting even for the first call, it is not valid. This is undefined behavior. Because after the stack unwinding happens(control returning from `inptr()` to `main()`, the `i`disappears and any value at the address of it could not be found.

You can make it static to work.

```
int* intptr ()
{
    static int i = 0;
    i=rand();
    printf("%d_____",i);
    return(&i);

 }
```